# How do Jedi Deal With Childcare?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, jedi-training

Jedi bring in children at a very young age. The age would obviously be younger than nine years as Anakin was labeled as “too old” by the Council in TPM.

With an even younger child, how do you train them on the force if they are less-attentive and more apt to get into trouble (toddlers-7 years)?

Are there any sources (in or out-of-universe) that confirm how the Jedi take care of and raise the brand new force-sensitive younglings they bring in to train?

Canon preferred, Legends is acceptable.

Comment: Badly, if their historical safeguarding issues are anything to go by. Namely, being able to safeguard their younglings from a madman with a lightsaber.

Comment: In nurseries with Jedi masters as staff/carers, presumably

Comment: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jedi_Temple_dormitory

Comment: Truly wonderful, the method of Jedi childcare is.

Comment: Legends info here; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ihWYL0cBTSo

Comment: Simply being isolated from non-Jedi influences would be a form of (passive) training. Anakin is too old because he already has bad "habits" to break.

Answer (score 4):

In the Legends continuity, before they are old enough to train, young Jedi recruits are placed in a nursery. They are attained to by medical droids.

[image]

We see this in *Star Wars Tales* #13.

Comment: Interesting information. I am curious about the toddler years, as well as 1-3 years old. Before a Force-sensitive knows how to walk. How early do Jedi start training? Before so, are these younglings just cared for like in an orphanage? Are parents allowed to visit?

Comment: @MissouriSpartan We know that communication between Jedi and their families was forbidden.

Comment: This image breaks my heart. </3 [Related](https://youtu.be/N3Zj-hMEL-k)